# Gatling DSL in Java

Tags: java, scala, gatling

I'm struggling to make a Gatling test running in Java code.
Anybody here please know an example code of reference of how to use the DSL of Gatling from Java?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exist at the current moment but it will be supported in the next version of 3.7.0
https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4144

Comment: Any example using Scala DSL of Gatling from Java?

Comment: @paul https://github.com/gatling/gatling/commit/58a5477e7f0de2e77857d9ac85144f62d10e4e34#diff-77f9e50f322d7637a3463cf2f1d02884f1d59994017a5469ef3187df89cd816bR26

Comment: Yeah I tried the M2 version, but I cannot find a maven plugin to run the simulation. Any idea how to run a Simulation with that version?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you should give up on trying to use Gatling's Scala DSL from Java. Way too complicated.

As @Amerousful said, we'll be releasing a Java DSL in Gatling 3.7 in a few weeks (currently working on polishing and revamping all the doc). I recommend you wait for it.

Comment: Yeah I tried the M2 version, but I cannot find a maven plugin to run the simulation. Any idea how to run a Simulation with that version?

Comment: Don't try to use those milestones. Those are unpolished internal releases. Please wait for the official release.